# Error : "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'flask'". Error during invocation of Lambda Python API

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to deploy a Python based lambda REST service (hello world) into AWS. here is my code snippet. and I am using GitHub CI/CD platform for automated deployment.

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

My GitHub Actions are

```
name: deploy-aws-lambda

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
        python-version: [3.7]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install flask && npm install
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-central-1
      - name: Install Serverless Framework
        run: npm install -g serverless
      - name: Serverless Deploy
        run: npm run-script deploy
```

During deployment, it is deploying and I can see in API Gateway. but on invocation I am afacing following error

```
Sat Jun 12 04:35:37 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'flask'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
```

my serverless.yaml file is as below

```
# serverless.yml

service: serverless-flask

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: app.hello
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    pythonBin: python3


functions:
  create:
    handler: app.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
          cors: true
```

Comment: You need to do pip install Flask and other python dependencies.

Comment: tried with pip install .. but getting following error .. Mon Jun 14 04:15:00 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'flask'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
Mon Jun 14 04:15:00 UTC 2021 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'flask'. Lambda request id: d7483c32-c6ea-436b-a062-ddd421198c6a
Mon Jun 14 04:15:00 UTC 2021 : Method completed with status: 502

Comment: Can you try the following changes: the value of `custom: app:` to `app.app` and `functions: dimensionierungstool: handler: wsgi_handler.handler` ?

Answer (score 0):

npm install flask doesn't look right to me. It is probably installing nodejs [Flask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flask) which is completely different from python flask. Log into your AWS console and check what is packaged along with your lambda function handler file. Also check if any layers are attached. And double check what the correct method for installing python dependencies using github CI/CD is.

Also, if you are open to changing your deployment strategy, have a look at [Zappa](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa). It is easy to deploy and is built for python.